# Coordinates of cereals in figure

Tags: machine-learning, cnn

I'm trying to automatize cereal counting from an image. The problem is that I have only a few pictures and I don't know how to train a CNN to do the job.

Should I create mini images with single cereals and use those to train the network?

I would like to extract the coordinates, not only count them.

[image]

Comment: If your data has bounding box annotations you can use object detection methods. If it doesn't then classical methods like clustering maybe can do the job.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any open library (R or python) to do that?

Comment: For object detection or clustering?

Comment: Object detection. Clustering is simpler once you have the coordinates. My problem is with locating the cereals from the image.

Comment: You can try yolov5 for object detection. https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the link!